# Convert Oscillator output voltage level

Tags: oscillator, level-translation

I have a circuit of a USB chip (USB hub) with a custom external 24MHz oscillator. This oscillator have a max 3Vpp and the chip max voltage for XI is 2.45 with 1.8 recommended voltage.

What are the options to translate the output oscillator voltage? The simplest way is a resistor divider but a resistor have a intrinsic capacitance and inductance associated and XI may also not have an infinite impedance. Also found there are voltage translator chips but this means i also have to implement another 1.8V voltage rail and this is no option.

So, my question is what is the best solution?

Comment: It would be helpful if you tell which "USB chip" you are trying to interface, and with which oscillator (driver impedance is important).

Comment: It's a TUSB4020BI

Answer (score 1):

No one has "infinite input impedance", and everything has "intrinsic capacitance and inductance associated". The question is how much these parasitic parameters would affect the signal. All you need is to have a signal strong enough to toggle the input buffer of XTAL circuitry near 1.8V/2 input threshold, or 900 mV +- 200 mV, that's it.

If you want to reduce a 3.3 V signal coming externally from an oscillator over transmission line (PCB trace), just terminating the signal with characteristic impedance (say, typical trace of 60 - 65 Ohms) at XI point will instantly halve the voltage, without any divider. The transmission line will be that divider, especially if you match the transmission line impedance at input side using some reasonable series resistor (22 - 33 Ohms, at oscillator end). There will be no reflections or any other ugliness to worry about.

So, the short answer is that all these "intrinsics" are totally negligible at 24 MHz or even ant much higher frequencies. Your worries are absolutely unfounded.

Comment: Did some tests. Without any divider and only with the signal line pcb trace, the voltage is kept at 3VPP. With 22 Ohms at oscillator end, the voltage is 2.9Vpp

Comment: @LuisCarlos, and what about having 60-Ohms (parallel) termination at the receiver end?